# Duplicados en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

podrian ayudarme, no se me ocurre como eliminar los registros duplicados de esta consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       VendorName
     , Vendor
     , Reference
     , DocumentNumber
     , ClearingDocument
     , DocumentDate
     , ClearingDate
     , '' AS 'TDP'
     , '' AS 'SAP'
     , DocumentCurrency
     , 0 AS 'WF'
     , CASE
           WHEN DocumentCurrency = 'MXN' THEN AmountInDocCurr
       ELSE 0
       END as 'MXN'
     , CASE
           WHEN DocumentCurrency = 'USD' THEN AmountInDocCurr
       ELSE 0
       END as 'USD'
     , AmountInDocCurr
     , Round(VATAmount / 0.16, 2) AS 'Base16'
     , Round(NetAmount - Round(VATAmount / 0.16, 2), 2) AS 'Base0'
     , 0 AS 'Base8'
     , 0 AS 'Exento'
     , Round(VATAmount, 2) AS 'IVA16'
     , 0 AS 'IVA8'
     , WithholdingTaxAmnt AS 'IVARet'
     , 0 AS 'ISRRet'
     , AmountInDocCurr AS 'TotalFactura'
     , CASE
           WHEN DocumentCurrency = 'USD' THEN dbo.sp_getTCTypes3
                                              ( ClearingDate )
       ELSE 1
       END as 'TC'
     , TextField
       FROM Tbl_MXInvoices
       WHERE Month(ClearingDate) = 8 AND Year(ClearingDate) = 2021;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! duplicados basados en que?

Comment: podrías intentar agregar la liga a un sqlfiddle así podemos reproducir el problema